# Getting python application to access the certificate stored in windows certificate manager

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, ssl

I have API.crt stored in windows certificate manager -> Trusted Root Certification Authorities. The list shows name of certificate as **'localhost'**

When I run below code, it works when I provide the path to certificate in `load_verify_locations()` function.

But it does not works when I retrieve the certificate from windows cert manager and provide the actual certificate. Please can anyone help me out in working this.

```
import wincertstore
import ssl
for storename in ("CA", "ROOT"):
    with wincertstore.CertSystemStore(storename) as store:
        for cert in store.itercerts(usage=wincertstore.SERVER_AUTH):
            if cert.get_name() == 'localhost': #name of cert
                mycert = cert.get_pem()


context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
context.load_verify_locations("C:/API.crt") ##Works if certificate is stored locally
context.load_verify_locations(mycert) ## Does not Works if certificate is passed.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 14, in <module>
    context.load_verify_locations(mycert) ## Does not Works if certificate is passed.
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`SSLContext.load_verify_locations()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html?highlight=ssl#ssl.SSLContext.load_verify_locations) method takes three keyword arguments:

- `cafile`

  > the path to a file of concatenated CA certificates in PEM format
- `capath`

  > the path to a directory containing several CA certificates in PEM format
- `cadata`

  > either an **ASCII string of one or more PEM-encoded certificates** or a bytes-like object of DER-encoded certificates

Due to `mycert = cert.get_pem()`, `mycert` is the **ASCII PEM string** of that certificate, not a *path* to a certificate.

In both calls, you're passing the parameter as a positional, so it gets assigned to the first keyword argument (`cafile`). In the first call, your argument is indeed a path to a file, so it works as expected. In the second, it is not a filepath, so the call fails with `FileNotFoundError`.

If you change the second call to `context.load_verify_locations(cdata=mycert)` to specify that your argument is a PEM string, I suspect it will work.